# Remaining space when using auto layout space constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm trying to use auto layout for automatically resize my scroll view. Although I created space constraints as 0, there are 16 pixels space from both left and right sides of the screen in run time.

Design time picture:

[image: autolayout]

Comment: nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you uncheck **Constrain to margins** checkbox option when creating the constraint?

Comment: Ozgur, yes I had checked them.

Comment: I created them without check. It worked.

Comment: may be you should write it as answer

Comment: @zontragon there is already an answer below regarding this. You can mark it as accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncheck Constrain to margins option

[image: uncheck Constrain to margins]